# Mathematica manipulate control steps are too big with list as variable for manipulate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Jeez, first of all I realize my question sounds kinda confusing, but it's the clearest I could formulate it....

Anyway, my problem:

I am trying to load curves from a large SQL database. All the loading works after many headaches, but now I come to the point I want to visualize all this data. My manipulate code looks something like this:

```
Manipulate[
ListPlot[IVcurve[mid]],
{mid, listofmids, DisplayAllSteps->True, AppearanceElements-> {"StepLeftButton","StepRightButton"}}, 
ControlType -> Manipulator]
```

Where, "mid" is a measurement ID, and "listofmids" is a list of all these IDs. Why you ask? Because I have right you about thirty Current-Voltage curves from solar panels that I would like to analyse visually. In order to do this, I would like to be able to go through them all. But both the slider and the "Step Buttons" skip a lot of the measurement IDs in the list "listofmids". I would like to click or slide along all of the curves, if possible... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach the rest of your code. Specially the parts where you have defined IVcurve, and listofmids?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[30, {30}], {i, 0, 100}];
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[data[[i]]],
    {i, 1, Length[data], 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image: manipulate]